# Cannot import folder into project in Aptana

Tags: python, aptana

I want to import a python package foo into a new project in Aptana.
I tried two methods: 1. promote file folder to project and 2. import folder into a new project.

In both cases, the error: "no module named foo.filename" occurs when I try to run
a program in a subfolder. The parent folder is called foo. The code is:

from foo.filename import *

There are no reference errors when executing this file outside Aptana.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each folder in your package contains an:

```
__init__.py file.
```

If the package folder is not inside of the projects root source directory you may want to add it to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: Thanks. There is an __init__.py in the parent and in the child directory. The folder foo was imported into Aptana via 'promote to project'. The directory structure is: /foo/__init__.py /foo/child/__init__.py, test.py. test.py contains one line: from foo import *. This fails with the error "no module named foo". How can I fix this?